# How to invoke an ActionScript method from JavaScript (HTMLLoader) object in AIR?

Tags: actionscript, air

So I have an Application Sandbox HTMLLoader object which I create in [AIR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Integrated_Runtime) and simply want to call [ActionScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript) methods from [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript). In Flash, this is accomplished through our trusty **ExternalInterface.addCallback()** function. However in AIR, things are quite a bit different, and I just can't seem to get it to work.

Here is a simplified overview of my project:

My AIR (ActionScript) main:

```
public class Main extends Sprite {

    public var _as3Var:String = "testing";
    public function as3Function():void
    {
        trace("as3Function called from Javascript");
    }

    public function Main() {
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, onInvoke);
    }

    protected function onInvoke(e:InvokeEvent):void {
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.removeEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, onInvoke );
        var app = new App();
        addChild(app);
        app.init(new ExternalContainer(), e.currentDirectory, e.arguments);
    }
}
```

And this is how I create my HTMLLoader object:

```
{
    _html = new HTMLLoader();
    _html.useCache = false;
    _html.runtimeApplicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
    _html.load(new URLRequest("sandbox/AirRoot.html"));
    _html.width = 800;
    _html.height = 600;
    App.ref.addChild(_html);
}
```

And at last, here is my snippet of JavaScript in my **AirRoot.html** file which is trying to call the public method **as3Function()** declared in my Main class:

```
Exposed.testAs3 = function()
{
    air.trace("Exposed.testAs3 called");            /* This works fine. */
    air.trace("runtimeVersion:");                   /* This works fine. */
    air.trace(air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.runtimeVersion);  /* This works fine. */
    air.trace("seeing if I can get to AS3 params...");  /* This works fine. */

    /* This doesn't work - get the following error: TypeError: Value undefined does not allow function calls. */
    air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.as3Function();
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I am going to answer my own question. I promise this was not a ploy to gain more reputation points, but I was seriously confused today but have now found the appropriate answers and documentation - which is usually the main problem to many an engineer's question...

Anyway, the answer:

The AIR HTMLLoader object contains a magical property, `HTMLLoader.window`, which is a proxy to the JavaScript window object. So setting `HTMLLoader.window = AS3Function;` is one way - or in relation to my previously included example (assuming I setup a static property called Main which pointed to the Main class):

```
_html.window.as3Function = Main.as3Function;
```

And now in JavaScript I can just call `as3Function` as:

```
<script>
    window.as3Function();
</script>
```

Another interesting property is the JavaScript "window.htmlLoader" object. It is a proxy to the AS3 HTMLLoader parent object, in my case, the _html object.  From this you can access things in relation to the _html object from JavaScript.

Comment: How did you manage to mark it as the accepted answer? Anyway, thanks for this! My problem is that I need to call it the other way around (AS->JS) but I'll find it somewhere.

Comment: AS->JS can be found here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285384/can-i-print-an-htmlloader-pdf-in-adobe-air  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a change in the new version of AIR, but you no longer need to reference the window in the javascript call, you can just do this:

```
<script>
  as3Function();
</script>
```

Comment: That's just how JS works: `window` is the global scope so generally you don't have to explicitly reference `window`, for example `window.location` is the same as `location`, `new window.Array()` is the same as `new Array()`, etc.